# How to loop through each button to check if they are enabled or not?

Tags: vb.net, button, loops, for-loop, each

I want to do a For Each loop where i can check whether each button is enabled or disabled. If the button is enabled then i have to obtain the values in the tags for each button. I have 26 buttons each containing different values (cash prizes).*IMPORTANT: this code needs to go under the button so every sixth time its pressed it checks the buttons.

Pseudo-Code:

```
btncase1.tag = 5
Begin while statement to go through each button
   Check each button to see if it is enabled
   If button is enabled then obtain values
Next
```

Actual code i have but it doesnt make any sense to me:

```
Public Class Form1
Dim button As Button
Dim totalremcases As Integer
Dim btncase As New Control
Dim btncollection As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection()

Private Sub btncase1_Click()
For Each button As Button In btncollection
    If btncase.Enabled Then
        totalremcases = totalremcases + CInt(btncase.Tag)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Is this already working code you are working with and you just don't understand it so you want it explained or is there a specific error? Are all the buttons added to the btnCollection?

Answer (score 5):

you can try to solve it by using this approach

```
  Public Sub getallcontrolls(controls As System.Web.UI.ControlCollection)
    Dim myAL As New ArrayList()
    For Each ctrl As Control In controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is Button Then
            If ctrl.Enabled = True Then
                Dim tag As String = ctrl.Tag.ToString()
                myAL.Add(tag)
            End If

        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: but this is a private sub right, so i wont work under a button will it? Because i need it to check after a num of times so afyer btn is clicked six times, then check wht btns are enabled and obtain the values in their tags

Answer (score 0):

It seem that you are making a "Deal or No Deal" kind of game.

You can create a button click counter (form level variable) so that you can keep track of how many buttons are clicked already. Increment the counter every time a button is clicked.

Create a function to accumulate values of the tags. You call this function only if the counter is divisible by 6. (You said you check every sixth time a button is pressed)

```
Dim counter As Integer
Dim total As Integer

Private Function AccumulateTags() As Integer
    Dim ctl As Control
    Dim total As Integer
    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf ctl Is Button Then
            If ctl.Enabled = True Then
                total += Val(ctl.Tag)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Return total
End Function

Private Function disable(sender As Object)
    Dim ctl As Control
    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf ctl Is Button AndAlso sender.Equals(ctl) Then
            ctl.Enabled = False
        End If
    Next
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click, _
              Button2.Click, Button3.Click, Button4.Click, Button5.Click, Button6.Click, Button7.Click
    counter += 1
    If counter Mod 6 = 0 Then 'Checks if counter is divisible by 6
        total = AccumulateTags()
    End If

    MsgBox("Total" & total) 'Displays total. You may also display it in a label if you want
    disable(sender)
End Sub
```